# Understanding why table cell doesn't wrap its 100% percent height content

Tags: html, css, css-tables

**Original question (EDITED)**

> CSS: Why table-cell sibling with height 100% exceeds table-row body

I am testing CSS table. In one of my test I'm trying to get an equal height column layout.

- I want an "aside" at the left which should fill 100% of the page height (e.g column).
- A the right of "aside", I want an "header" above a "main" content.
- I want "header" and "main" to fill 100% of the page height.
- I want the whole layout height to grow when their content grow.

Here's my test example : https://jsfiddle.net/264z0ovf/

I set "aside" as a table-cell and set "main" height to 100%. This results in "main" having exactly 100% of its parent's height and overflowing the bottom of "body".

**Can you explain why "main" with 100% height overflow the "body" table-row ?**

I was not expecting the overflow. I thought "main" would fill the remaining space below "header" or either the table to grow and wrap the whole height.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  display: table;
}

body {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  display: table-row;
}

aside {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  display: table-cell;
}

header {
  background-color: #909090;
}

main {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <aside>ASIDE</aside>
  <header>HEADER<br>AND SOME CONTENT</header>
  <main>MAIN</main>
</body>

</html>
```

**TL;DR**

I know percent height is computed from the parent's height.
So if "main" height is 100% then it would mean 100% of "body".

Next to "header" is a **sibling anonymous table-cell** which should wrap "aside" and "main". So the body table-row should also grow when its cells grow.
From https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes

> Any table element will automatically generate necessary anonymous
>   table objects around itself

This is another example where "main" doesn't overflow the table : https://jsfiddle.net/80a53fvs/

- I added a 100% height div table to wrap "header" and "main".
- I changed "main" as a table-row and left its height to 100%.

This results in "main" filling the remaining height below "header" without overflowing the table.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  display: table;
}

body {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  display: table-row;
}

aside {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  display: table-cell;
}

div {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: #909090;
}

main {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
   <aside>ASIDE</aside>
    <div>
      <header>HEADER<br>AND SOME CONTENT</header>
      <main>MAIN</main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: main is 100% of its container which is the body then you place it under the header so its the height of the header + the height of the body container = main height

Comment: @KJEK-Code I agree with your explanation but I don't understand why it overflow the body table row. Isn't the body row supposed to grow if its cell grows ?

Comment: ok, so I understand you would like it to cover the entire window without any scroll and that you would like the parent container to change as the content does but what I cannot figure out is why you want this to behave like a table.  Why wouldn't you just use a table to begin with? What is your end result? You already understand the mathematics behind how the overflow scroll appears what more would you like to understand?

Comment: @KJEK-Code I'm testing CSS Table (not HTML Table) so I'm expecting it to behave like a table but it doesn't because main height overflows, so that's the problem I want to understand here. I thought you could put anything in a table (html has display table and body has table-row) then it would grow so its content never overflow.

Comment: Setting something to display table, row, or cell does not apply any sort of magical property that does not allow it to overflow its container when given a height.  I think what need to be explained it the parent child relationship in regards to height.  if you have 2 objects (lets just say divs) one called content div the other full div one has content with no height the other is just 100% height. Content will equal the size of its children (content) while full will equal the size of its parent place them on top of each other and you get content + fulls parent height

Comment: as far as your second example: if you constrain two objects inside of a div and that div is set to 100% height the div will not allow its children exceed that 100% height limitation unless the content completely pushes itself out. Meaning it has to exceed both height and width limitation and at that point it has nowhere else to go.  Think of it like a cardboard box.. a box of the same size will fit inside but if you add another smaller box it wont. Now if you could tell your original box to never let anything inside fill it up the boxes inside will always become smaller the more you add.

Comment: @KJEK-Code In my 2nd example header height is not 0 and I set main height to 100% so I'd have a total height = header height + 100% but the parent div did constraint its children heights and prevented main to push itself out. The div would be the cardboard box but here it has forced the 100% height main to shrink because the div already had a non zero height header. I don't understand why this height constraint doesn't apply in the 1st example. _Sorry if I'm insisting on it, I know SO comments are not for chat, I just want to understand and I appreciate help/feedback no matter what_

Comment: No worries,  I get it you want to understand. When I say no height I mean the height  css property is not set on that object allowing its height to be dictated by the height of its content (children) it does not apply to the first example because the body has overflow scroll if you wanted the body to behave like the div in your second example you would need to set body { overflow: hidden } but keep in mind this is not the same as allowing parent height to dictate child height. (see edited answer)

Comment: @KJEK-Code Thanks for your help, I've improved my understanding, edited and add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

added

```
body {
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  display: table;
}

body {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  display: table-row;
  overflow: hidden;
}

aside {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  display: table-cell;
}

header {
  background-color: #909090;
}

main {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <aside>ASIDE</aside>
    <header>HEADER<br>AND SOME CONTENT</header>
    <main>MAIN</main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: we still have the same issue like you commented: 100vh is the size of the screen then we add the height of the header and we have the same overflow

Comment: @KJEK-Code Thank you but I was looking for an explanation not really for a solution. As he said, using 100vh is not a solution either since the body height will be something like height of header + 100vh so you'll get overflow + scrollbar. Plus I want the whole initial layout to fit exactly 100% of the page i.e just like a full page table without scrollbar.

Comment: @cedlog - I think this provides a clue though. When the table-row height depends on the table-cell height (grows to fit) and the table cell height depends on the table-row height (100% + header height) you have a circular dependency that cannot be resolved satisfactorily. So the table-cell content overflows the table-cell, table-row, and table. With (100vh + header height) there is no circular dependency and the table row can grow to meet the constraints.

Comment: @Alohci Can you please explain how this circular dependency is NOT happening in my 2nd example where I add a css table div to wrap {header,main} and set main as a table-row ?

Comment: @cedlog - No I can't wholly explain your second example. 100% on a table-row is probably being treated somewhat differently as being part of the structure of the table. rather than the contents of a table cell as in your first example, but the exact algorithm used there isn't known to me. In general, CSS tables are a black art once you get into the edge cases. The CSS tables spec hasn't been updated in a long time and has just never received the rigorous treatment it really needs.

Comment: @Alohci Thanks for your help, I've improved my understanding, edited and add an answer.